# Funções com ajax

Tags: php, ajax

Eu utilizo este código para trabalhar com ajax. Funciona perfeitamente.
Porém é um código fixo, mas eu gostaria de colocar TODOS os códigos que eu faço via ajax e colocar num arquivo só e depois chamar via funções.

Exemplo:

arquivodefuncoes.js

```
cadastroUsuario(){
//aqui dentro meu ajax
}

cadastroDependentes(){
//aqui dentro meu ajax
}
```

Eu não sei trabalhar com funções e chamando essas funções. Com isto, eu trabalho via submit do formulário. Porém, eu tenho que ficar colocando o código abaixo de todo formulario que eu tenho, sendo assim, fica bagunçado meus arquivos.

Como eu poderia trabalhar criando funções e chamando no `button` ao invés de colocar o código abaixo do `</form>`?

```
<form method=post id="simples-formulario-ajax">
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="enviar" value="enviar" id="enviar" disabled>
        Selecione a Cor para Prosseguir :)
    </button> 
</form>


<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#simples-formulario-ajax').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    if($('#enviar').val() == 'Enviando...'){
        return(false);
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: 'carrinho.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'html',
        data: {
            'acao': $('#acao').val(),
            'cod': $('#cod').val(),
            'cor': $('input:radio[name=cor]:checked').val()
        }
    }).done(function(data){
        window.location.href = "cart&";                                                                         
        //alert(data);
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: A pergunta não está clara o suficiente. Você quer pegar o conteúdo de preventDefault() até alert() e reutilizar em outros lugares? É isso?

Comment: Na verdade não. Eu estou chamando via submit, mas ao invés de submit eu gostaria de fazer via função. Para assim eu ter um arquivo com funções distintas e não vários código igual o de cima espalhados em vários lugares do meu projeto

Comment: É, eu não entendi a pergunta mesmo então.

Comment: vou editar minha pergunta

Comment: @epx editei minha pergunta

Comment: Você pode trocar o <script> que contém código por um <script src=arquivodefuncoes.js></script> e deslocar tudo que estava dentro do <script> para dentro desse arquivo.

Comment: Note que você não precisa meter o código numa função, pode deixar ele no escopo principal, aí ele vai executar assim que o arquivodefuncoes.js for carregado.

Comment: Existem várias formas de fazer o que quer, se atente ao `evento(click, blur, focus, submit, etc...)` , as formas de `incluir(o ou os arquivos contendo as funções)`, o `escopo`...

Comment: @MagicHat é isto mesmo que preciso, mas não consigo fazer. Pode adaptar meu código para onClick?

Comment: Não é assim que as coisas funcionam,  você mesmo pode adaptar seu código para o uso do `onclick`. Se tiver dúvida específica, pode perguntar...

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

Coloque uma `class` nos forms que você quer enviar via AJAX. Por exemplo, `.form-ajax`, e também o `action` para onde ele será enviado (não precisa de `id` nem de `method`):

```
<form class="form-ajax" action="carrinho.php">
        ↑                 ↑
```

No evento `.submit` você irá usar como seletor a classe `.form-ajax`, ou seja, todo formulário que tiver essa classe será enviado via AJAX:

```
$('.form-ajax').submit(function(e){
```

Agora você precisa atribuir o formulário que disparou o evento `submit` numa variável, pois ela poderá ser usada dentro do `$.ajax`:

```
var $this = $(this);
```

Nas opção `url` do AJAX você irá pegar o atributo `action` do form:

```
url: $this.attr("action"),
```

E na opção `data`, você irá usar o método `.serializeArray()`, que retorna todos os campos do formulário em forma de objeto:

```
data: $this.serializeArray()
```

O código ficará assim:

```
$('.form-ajax').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   var $this = $(this);

   if($('#enviar').val() == 'Enviando...'){
      return false;
   }

   $.ajax({
      url: $this.attr("action"),
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'html',
      data: $this.serializeArray()
   }).done(function(data){
      window.location.href = "cart&";                                                                         
   });

});
```

No caso do redirecionamento `window.location.href = "cart&";`, que poderá variar dependendo do formulário, você pode fazer da seguinte forma, colocando um `data-redir` no form:

```
data-redir="cart&"
```

E no `.done` você irá buscar o valor desse atributo `data-redir`. Se ele não existir, não faz nada:

```
if($this.data("redir")){
   window.location.href = "cart&";                                                                         
}
```

Então o form ficaria assim agora:

```
<form class="form-ajax" action="carrinho.php" data-redir="cart&">
```

E o código:

```
$('.form-ajax').submit(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();

   var $this = $(this);

   if($('#enviar').val() == 'Enviando...'){
      return false;
   }

   $.ajax({
      url: $this.attr("action"),
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'html',
      data: $this.serializeArray()
   }).done(function(data){
      if($this.data("redir")){
         window.location.href = $this.data("redir");                                                                         
      }
   });

});
```